# calculation of variance function equation

Tags: statistics

I have an error in this code as I want to calculate the variance between the values in the(x1) and (x2) list. any recommendation?!

```
def my_var(L):
    s = 0
    t = 0
    u = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        s += L[i]
        t = s/len(L)
        u += ((L[i]-t)*(L[i]-t))
    return u / len(L)
x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
x2 = [1, -4, 7, 2]
v1 = my_var(x1)
v2 = my_var(x2)
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it Python? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try numpy.

```
import numpy as np
x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
x2 = [1, -4, 7, 2]
v1 = np.var(x1)
v2 = np.var(x2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I would like to solve it with the simple way
I think I have a problem in this line
u += ((L[i]-t)*(L[i]-t))

Answer (score 1):

You're doing many things incorrectly based on how I learned prob and stats. You need to calculate the average (mean) and then sum each value subtracted by the mean, squared. Then finally take that numerator and divide by 1 less than the sample size (n-1).

```
def my_var(L):
    mean = float(sum(L) / Len(L))
    numerator = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        numerator += (L[i]-mean)**2
    return numerator / (len(L) - 1)
x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
x2 = [1, -4, 7, 2]
v1 = my_var(x1)
v2 = my_var(x2)
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Without using sum:

```
def my_var(L):
    my_sum = 0
    mean = 0
    numerator = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        my_sum += L[i]
    mean = float(my_sum / len(L))
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        numerator += (L[i]-mean)**2
    return numerator / (len(L) - 1)
x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
x2 = [1, -4, 7, 2]
v1 = my_var(x1)
v2 = my_var(x2)
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Comment: Thank you really for your help but still does not work. Actually, I understand the equation well, as u mentioned first I have to calculate the mean and the sum of the square of difference between each value and the mean over the number of values only(not -1). when I checked in my code till the  t = s/len(L) it works. but the problem in the next line for sure 
u += ((L[i]-t)*(L[i]-t)) .if you could modify this part I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your problem is that you are computing it incorrectly in your example that you posted. Your `t` should be x-bar(mean) and it is not that. You have a few fundamental flaws, so anything but a complete rewrite is wrong. I edited the post to fix my errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @billy_ferguson. I have modified your code and it works. Execuse me, I am still an amateur but could you replace float and sum function and use simpler arithmetic operators as len(L) and += in this line mean = float(sum(L) / len(L))

```
def my_var(L):
    mean = 0
    numerator = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        mean = float(sum(L) / len(L))
        numerator += (L[i]-mean)**2
    return numerator / len(L)
x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
x2 = [1, -4, 7, 2]
v1 = my_var(x1)
v2 = my_var(x2)
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Comment: Don't do that. Very bad. You're repeating the same thing in a loop that doesn't change. You could compute the sum by looping on list L and summing that with `+=`, but sum is a built in language utility so and I believe it comes with the standard python build.